# Is ROS still maintained are any other trendy alternatives?

Tags: ros

I know this question is off-topic, but here I might get the answer.

Recently I started collaborating in a project based on ROS and I find several examples outdated, some repositories I am interested in have hundred of pull requests but are not merged. The supported Ubuntu versions are old.

My point is, ROS project does not give me confidence as other open-source projects. I hope I am wrong, but that is my impression after going throwout the guides and other documents.

By the way, the guides for beginners are quite detailed and easy to follow, but when one starts digging deeper, finds the lack of activity, like if people migrated, using other alternatives.

Either, the project is not widely adopted, or consumers of this software make their own improvements and keep them private.

If this is the reality, are there other know alternatives?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Snake Sanders, but I'm afraid that questions which ask a list of alternatives are effectively opinion polls, which are [discouraged on stack exchange](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/). We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so as you suggest, your questionis off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works, come and [chat] about it.

Comment: @Mark Booth, I knew it was not an appropriated question here, I received my answer, you can delete this post if you consider it not suitable here. Thank you

Comment: No, that's Ok, as long as it is closed it acts as an example of a question that shouldn't be asked. It was inconsiderate of you to ask a question knowing it was off topic however.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ROS Melodic supports 18.04, the current LTS-version of Ubuntu, so it's perfectly up to date.

ROS has a huge active community in Academia and(!) Industry ([ROSIndustrial)](https://rosindustrial.org/), many robotic companies use it in their products and ROS2 is currently under development.

A lot of ROS-packages have been written by people during their studies which have moved on later, so they dropped the support for the specific package. But the core components are continuously updated (although the focus is now more on ROS2).

ROS is not going to be replaced soon, so it's a save bet to use it.

Comment: appreciated your answer, thank you